# Saving files returned by an async asmx webservice

Tags: c#, silverlight, download

On an event (say a button click) my Silverlight application should issue an **async** web service call requesting for the file (with the filename, say Document1.pdf). The webservice (asmx) returns the file as a byte array.

How to let the user save this file locally at a desired location as he would for a normal file download.

Comment: I think the following helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024267/saving-files-in-silverlight-and-asynchronous-call-backs

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight 3.0 and above support a SaveFileDialog class that you can use provided you already have your array of bytes back from your stream.

There is a good example (although you may have to fit it to another model [like if you use MVVM]), but the result is the same.  You can allow the user to choose a file and save a byte stream after receiving a complete file in a byte[] array asynchronously on succession.

[Using the SaveFileDialog in Silverlight](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-SaveFileDialog-in-Silverlight-3.aspx)